# mocks-server with OpenApi

Tags: mocking

I have an OpenAPI YAML definition and I'm looking for a way to generate fixtures from it. It looks like `@mocks-server/main` can maybe do it but I've read through the [instructions](https://www.mocks-server.org/docs/integrations/openapi/) and I can't get it to work.

I've tried following their stuff and creating the following sample files:

#### `/mocks/testopenapi.json`

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Testing API",
    "description": "OpenAPI document to create routes"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/health": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "content": {
              "application/json0": {
                "examples": {
                  "message": {
                    "value": "Example"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### `/mocks/openapi/definitions.js`

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    basePath: "/api-1",
    "collection": "api",
    document: {
      $ref: "../testopenapi.json"
    }
  }
];
```

When I visit `/api-1/health` I get a 404. Does anyone know how to use this?